# How to convert from String Operation a [sign] b without if.

Tags: java, string, integer, character-arrays

The code calculates the result from the Expression a [sign] b .
**Possible operations: + - *** . Can i solve this exercise without using condition if?

```
  String result =  "3 + 6 = ";
   String result = outputStream.toString();
        String[] resultArray = result.split(" ");
        Integer first = Integer.parseInt(resultArray[0]);
        Integer second = Integer.parseInt(resultArray[2]);
        String opp = resultArray[1];

        if("+".equals(opp)){
            System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first + second));
        }
        else if("-".equals(opp)){
            System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first - second));
        }
        else if("*".equals(opp)){
            System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first * second));
        }
```

Comment: Use a `switch` block instead?

Comment: Maybe you are about c++ Operator overloading, but in Java there is no such language fty.

Comment: i'd hope there is the operation like String.format or some RegEX for easily convertion operations[*,+,-].

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a switch-case:

```
    switch (opp.charAt(0)) {
    case '+':
        System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp,
                second, first + second));
        break;
    case '-':
        System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp,
                second, first - second));
        break;
    case '*':
        System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp,
                second, first * second));
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can avoid the condition in two ways - using a `switch`, and using a `Map`:

With a `switch` statement:

```
if (opp.length() != 1)
    // Show error, and exit.
switch(opp.charAt(0)) {
case '+':
    System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first + second));
    break;
case '-':
    System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first - second));
    break;
case '*':
    System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, first * second));
    break;
default:
    // Show error...
    break;
}
```

With a `Map<K,V>` and a special-purpose interface:

```
interface Operation {
    int calc(int a, int b);
}
Map<String,Operation> ops = new HashMap<String,Operation> {
    {"+", new Op() {public calc(int a, int b) {return a+b;}}}
,   {"-", new Op() {public calc(int a, int b) {return a-b;}}}
,   {"*", new Op() {public calc(int a, int b) {return a*b;}}}
};
...
Operation op = ops.get(opp);
if (op == null)
    // Report an error and exit
System.out.println(String.format("%d %s %d = %d", first, opp, second, op(first, second)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on some of the other answers (using a switch statement or a map), I think the cleanest solution is to move the operators into an enum:

```
public enum Operator {
    ADDITION("+") {
        public int operate(int a, int b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    },
    SUBTRACTION("-") {
        public int operate(int a, int b) {
            return a - b;
        }
    },
    MULTIPLICATION("*") {
        public int operate(int a, int b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    };

    private String symbol;

    private Operator(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public abstract int operate(int a, int b);

    public static Operator fromSymbol(String symbol) {
        for (Operator o : values()) {
            if (o.symbol.equals(symbol)) {
                return operator;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No operator with symbol " + symbol);
    }
}
```

Then you have a very simple API for getting the correct operator from its symbol (and vice versa), and it is very easy to add more (e.g. division). It also has the extra benefit of allowing you to pass around instances of `Operator`, and to address them by name directly (e.g. `Operator.ADDITION`).

```
String symbol = "*";
Operator o = Operator.fromSymbol(symbol);
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int result = o.operate(a, b);
```